# What is the difference between users presented in Identity and Access Managenment (IAM) and IAM identity center?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Once I added a user to my AWS account, and it is present on the "Identity and Access Management (IAM)" page now. But it is absent on "IAM Identity Center" page. Why?
Isn't "IAM Identity Center" just another way of managing the same users?
[image: Identity and Access Management (IAM)][image: IAM Identity Center]

I expect to see the same users in both "IAM Identity Center" and "IAM Identity Center".

Comment: It appears that IAM Identity Center is used to manage Single Sign-On (SSO), which is when users authenticate to a corporate datastore (eg Active Directory, LDAP). This differs from normal IAM, which creates users directly inside of AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IAM user and an IAM Identity Center user are [two distinct identities](https://repost.aws/questions/QUfNomVCt5TCiac7oQoT8n0A/can-i-keep-existing-iam-users-and-add-sso-to-our-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

The IAM Identity Center is designed for adding or inviting other AWS accounts to your organization account. It can also be used to create federated users or single sign on users. AWS recommends it when giving a user console access. On the other hand. Identity and Access Management Center is designed for creation of users so as to enable access to AWS resources. It is the best place to create IAM users for Access and Secret key generation

Answer (score 0):

As i understand IAM Identity center is something which sits outside of your accounts and you can create users there and also from separate idp.

In Identity center you can provide access to users across multiple accounts.
Moreover identity center users have different login url known as access portal url rather than the normal aws console login url

But an IAM user is created in a particular account and have access keys.
Yes, the same user can have console-signin as well (if enabled) but only on the particular account it was created in, unlike Identity center user who can have console access to multiple accounts(obviously if configured)

Generally a human user who needs portal access is preferably created in IAM Identity Center while a user who needs to programmatically access aws resources is preferably created as IAM user